# laravel mail Method 'to' not found in class

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4

I am following phpacademy's **Laravel 4 Authentication** tutorial series and have come across a stumbling block in the emailer section (part 6 of 16).

I'm completing this in phpstorm, with *_ide_helper.php* installed from https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/5227822

---

When I use the *Mail::send* method in the *HomeController.php* file, the code helper returns the following error message.

```
method "to" not found in class
```

Further explanation is given by

```
Referenced method not found in subject class
```

A point in the right direction for resolving this issue would be very much appreciated

---

Here is the full code for the HomeController class, including this Mail:send method which is causing issues:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController
{
    public function home()
    {
        Mail::send('emails.auth.test', array('name'=>'User'), function($message)
    {
        $message->to('user@gmail.com','User')->subject('Test');
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Have you tried run it in your browser? Maybe it's a bug in your code helper.

Comment: yeah I have tried to run it in the browser and it returns the "Whoops, looks like something went wrong" page.

Comment: Check your `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` if there's any error message. You could also change `debug` to true in `app/config/app.php` so you see the error message on your browser.

Comment: Thanks so much Unnawut. Once I enabled the debugger I was able to see that the issue was in the sender address. I'd made a rookie mistake in the mail.php config file. This is now fixed an I have sent and received a test email =)

Comment: Glad you solved it! Maybe add how you solved it as an answer too :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, it's misconfigured mail.php. Check your mail.php configuration, try telnet or some other tool to validate your credentials if using STMP.